# Transform String in Number for Comparison

Tags: string, numbers, unique, transform

I need your help with a small problem.

It there a possibility (in Java or an abstract solution) to transform a arbitrary String into an Integer with the property, that the alphabetically ordering does also work with the Integer?

Example:
House < Tree < Zoo in alphabetically order.

I would like to transform those Strings into Integer, so that the ordering is also available. Important is, that the concrete Strings are not known before. That means it should be a unique transformation.

I hope someone can help me.

Regards, 
Michael

Comment: Why? You can simply use String's [compareTo(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) or [compareToIgnoreCase(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) methods to sort Strings in a lexicographic order.

Comment: How do you **expect** the ordering to be different if, say, 'House' and 'Horse' were represented by integers?

Comment: Normally I would use this methods. But I use an external library for drawing trees. This lib has an compare-method which only use integer as representing the nodes. Therefore I needed this other way.

Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Let's say you have two strings which represent 1 and 2.  You can always make another string which would fit between them alphabetically e.g.

```
aa  = 1
ab  = 2
aaa = ???
```

If you know the strings you're dealing with have a maximum length, then this is possible.  For example, suppose your string has length <= 3.  Take a string abc, and convert each letter to a number, where A = 1, B = 2, ..., Z = 26.  If the string is less than 3 characters long, fill in the blanks at the end with zeroes.  Then the value is:

```
(a * 27 * 27) + (b * 27) + c
```

Then:

```
aa  = 756
ab  = 783
aaa = 757
```

Comment: develop a `hash` based on ASCII integer values and length??? not worth the effort IMO ... as @Bart mentions, the `compareTo(...)` etc. will sort in lexicographic order - I don't really see how anything else makes sense ...

Comment: You're right - ASCII values would probably be simpler.  And it's also hard to see why you'd want to do this, when `compareTo(...)` exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer thomson_matt. 
That's what I was searching for :)

Regards, Michael